# Problem with the chromedriver - " executable needs to be in PATH. "

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, bots

Im trying to do a WhatsApp bot with python.

The following error appears in terminal:

```
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '.chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. 
Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

But in running the .exe in the same directory as my python script

[image]

What id do?

Wheres the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mensagem = "BOT TEST"
        self.grupos = ["APS jogo", "Mine"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('land=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'.chromedriver.exe')



    def EnviarMensagens(self):

        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

        time.sleep(30)
        for grupo in self.grupos:
            grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")
            time.sleep(3)
            grupo.click()
            chatBox= self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1Plpp')
            time.sleep(3)
            chatBox.click()
            chatBox.send_keys(self.mensagem)
            botaoEnviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[data-icon='send']")
            time.sleep(3)
            botaoEnviar.click()
            time.sleep(3)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.EnviarMensagens()
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run `.chromedriver.exe`, when the binary is actually called `chromedriver.exe` (no leading `.`).

Comment: Or try this `driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: The best solution is to add `chromedriver.exe` to your windows system variable `PATH`, then there is no need to put the exe near your py file.

Comment: Hey, actually worked larsks. I just put a '.'. But now i had a new problem

Comment: I will try to solve it because other problems appear.